# SignalR request pipeline, Hub lifetime

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am starting on signalR with asp.net webapi, and I am trying to understand the whole signalR request/connection pipeline and what is the lifetime of the hub and who creates and dispose the hub instance (does it gets created on every communication between client and server?)

One of the reason is that we need to understand how we should be using an IoC contain in signalR request scenario, how we control the lifetime of the dependency correct specifically the **ISession** or **DBContext**.

Answer (score 10):

Hubs instances are created at every single request from a client. They are not kept around, therefore you should not put any state in them.

Hubs are created through a factory system which you can customize through its built-in [dependency injection mechanism](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection).

Comment: so it should be fine with scoping the lifetime of the ISession to the instance of the hub right? it will be disposed at the end of the request.

Comment: Unless you "mess" with hub's lifetime yourself by customizing its creation process (which you can do), I'd say yes.

Comment: By every request, do you mean every signalr message?  Or every connection?

Comment: @CamHart every SignalR message.

Comment: @Wasp Is is possible or recommended to have Hub as singleton?

Comment: @shatl possible but IMO you should not do it

Comment: @Wasp not sure how it was when this was posted, but hub instances are not created on every message or connection request, absolutely not

Comment: @Maya for SignalR 1 and 2 that was definitely the case in 2014, you can also check official docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server . If this is not valid anymore I have no idea, if you think so you are welcome to add a new answer describing the case today.